# Getting temporary table creation statements from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, temp-tables

In PostgreSQL you can create a temporary table very easily with:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_foo AS
SELECT bar, baz FROM some_table WHERE ...;
```

Is there any easy way to get a create statement for that table?  I can make queries to get information about the table structure (eg in psql I can use `\d`) but that doesn't give me a creation statement that I can use.

I would like this so that I can materialize queries in one PostgreSQL database, get the table structure of the query, create that temporary table in another, and then use `COPY` commands to copy data from one to the other before proceeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, reconstructing the `CREATE TABLE` statement gets pretty complicated, if you need to account for column defaults, foreign keys, check constraints, etc.

But the product of a `CREATE TABLE AS ...` statement won't have any of this, so it's relatively straightforward. Plug your table name into the `WHERE` clause of this query:

```
SELECT
  format(
    'CREATE TEMP TABLE %s (%s)',
    attrelid::regclass,
    string_agg(
      format(
        '%I %s',
        attname,
        format_type(atttypid, atttypmod)
      ),
      ','
      ORDER BY attnum
    )
  )
FROM pg_attribute
WHERE
  attrelid = 'tmp_foo'::regclass AND
  attnum > 0 AND
  NOT attisdropped
GROUP BY attrelid
```

---

As a side-note, instead of doing this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_foo AS SELECT ... ;
COPY tmp_foo TO STDOUT;
```

... you can get the structure of the `SELECT` result without actually running it, which avoids creating an intermediate copy of the data:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_foo AS SELECT ... WITH NO DATA;
COPY (SELECT ...) TO STDOUT;
```

Comment: Perfect!  It is too bad this isn't a native function.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest trick would be to use `pg_dump`:

```
$ pg_dump -s -t tmp_foo _dbname_
```

Of course, this will only work for a non-temporary table. But you could also just create a regular table and do a pipe like `pg_dump ... | psql ...` or `pg_dump ... | pg_restore ...` to do your task.

Comment: I have done things like that before, but there is a problem if I do not have permissions to create tables.  Also it is a code maintenance problem where every time the query changes, the table creation also has to change.  (I've seen that screw up too many times.)

Comment: Using `pg_dump` can get you past the query change problem, but not the permission one.

Comment: Using `pg_dump` can't automate the query change problem.

Comment: I don't see how it doesn't. It doesn't know anything about the query, it's just fetching a table from database A and writing it to database B.

Comment: So you're saying create real tables, then use pg_dump to transfer?  In principle that works for me right now.  But where I've done this in the past it would be a problem because then one user running code could get in the way of another.  (That is part of why temporary tables are so useful here.)

Comment: This suggests to me that you have per-user tables, which is a normalization smell. Probably you should have one big table that contains every user's stuff and have a system user do the moving around, then use views or procedures to confine access to that table to matching users.